# Is the translation of open and closed sets to some language non-antonym preserving?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Maybe more than one person though, before you were given the definition of *closed set*, that they were the sets that are not *open*, i.e. that the property of *open* and *closed* being antonyms were transferred to the logic.

**Q:** Is there a language in which the words that replace *open* and *closed* sets,  in the topological sense, are not antonyms?

Comment: Not really an answer, but here's a link to a document that discusses the differences in topological terminology and different languages: [here.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CE8QFjAG&url=https%3A%2F%2Fojs.upv.es%2Findex.php%2FAGT%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F1950%2F2058&ei=CEJ3VLvVOaSxsAT62ILQDA&usg=AFQjCNGXGY6QIXoyNocLby6LgLJ6sGNwKw&sig2=GoJ-pUXLiU-Uf5VphqKCJA&cad=rja)

Comment: Interesting, thanks.